# Sending a french email with phpMailer cause strange subject encoding

Tags: phpmailer

I'm sending for my system email to users.

For this purpose I used phpMailer.

For english email, no problems.

For french email, subject of the message starts like this:

`=?text/html; charset=UTF-8;?Q?Votre_essai_de_14_jours_a_d=C3=A9but=C3=A9?=`

Here the potential error code:

```
$Email_Subject = 'Votre essai de 14 jours a débuté';
$mail->CharSet = "text/html; charset=UTF-8;";
$mail->Encoding = "base64";
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject  = $Email_Subject;
$mail->Body = $messageHTML;
$mail->AltBody = $messageTEXT;
```

What can cause this behaviour ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It wants a character set, but you gave it a MIME content-type declaration, which is wrong. Simply do this:

```
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
```